# Strange service performance degradation when running it under Docker

Tags: docker

In the context of a distributed API, I am handling a "Giga" service which consumes about 15 Gb of memory and requires at least four CPUs. During bootstrapping, the service must load four files before it becomes available.

On my laptop, when I run the service without docker, I mean, from a shell, when I run it, the service takes about 9 seconds to become active. Once the service is active, 240 calls to the service takes around 7 seconds.

Now, when I run on my laptop precisely the same service, but this time under a Docker container, it takes about 6 minutes to load the files and become active. When I execute exactly the 240 calls mentioned above, the service takes around 5.5 minutes!!!!

This is the first time I have found a similar problem, and since I am not a Docker guru, I wonder if someone could give me clues about what could be happening.

This is the content of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.16 as dag_build

RUN apk add g++ make protobuf protobuf-dev grpc-dev \
    pkgconfig git gsl-dev tclap-dev

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/dag_service
WORKDIR /usr/src/dag_service
    
COPY model_services/protos/dag.proto /usr/src/protos/dag.proto

COPY model_services/dag/*.H /usr/src/dag_service/
COPY model_services/dag/dag_service.cc /usr/src/dag_service
COPY model_services/dag/Makefile /usr/src/dag_service
    
RUN cd /usr/src/dag_service; make dag_service

COPY model_services/dag/nfl_graph_q[1234]_130.txt.bz2 /usr/src/dag_service/

RUN cd /usr/src/dag_service; bunzip2 nfl_graph_q[1234]_130.txt.bz2

COPY model_services/dag/q[1234].Tree /usr/src/dag_service/

##################################################
# Run the dag service
FROM alpine:3.16 AS dag_runtime

RUN apk add protobuf-dev grpc-dev 
    
COPY --from=dag_build /usr/src/dag_service/nfl_graph_q[1234]_130.txt /bin/
COPY --from=dag_build /usr/src/dag_service/q[1234].Tree /bin/
COPY --from=dag_build /usr/src/dag_service/dag_service /bin/dag_service

WORKDIR /bin/

RUN mkdir -p /tmp
EXPOSE 6003
RUN chmod a+x dag_service

CMD ["./dag_service", "-s", "1 0 900 75 -1 3 3", "-s", "2 0 900 75 -1 3 3", "-s", "3 0 900 75 -1 3 3", "-s", "4 0 900 75 -1 3 3", "-d", "nfl_graph_q1_130.txt", "-d", "nfl_graph_q2_130.txt", "-d", "nfl_graph_q3_130.txt", "-d", "nfl_graph_q4_130.txt", "-p", "q1.Tree", "-p", "q2.Tree", "-p", "q3.Tree", "-p", "q4.Tree", "-m", "3e-8", "-l", "0.99"]
```

The service is written in C++.

My Laptop runs Linux, Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: What platform are you using Docker on? Are you using it on a platform where it's implemented using a virtual machine? eg. OS X, Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I am using Linux, concretely, Ubuntu 22.04. A thing that I did not mention in my post, the problem is also in AWS running K8S

Comment: Is this self-managed kubernetes, or ECS, or something else? Any differences between how the Docker version is run and how the non-Docker version is run?

Comment: We use ECS. The standalone service runs just as the command line, something like `/dag_service -s "1 0 900 75 -1 3 3" -s "2 0 900 75 -1 3 3" -s "3 0 900 75 -1 3 3" -s "4 0 900 75 -1 3 3" -d nfl_graph_q1_130.txt -d nfl_graph_q2_130.txt -d nfl_graph_q3_130.txt -d nfl_graph_q4_130.txt -p q1.Tree -p q2.Tree -p q3.Tree -p q4.Tree -m 3e-8 -l 0.99` in a shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the cause of the problem, or at least its symptom: the problem was Alpine. I replaced the Alpine image with one called `grpc/cxx:latest` taken from the docker library, and everything started to work as expected. The performance is similar to the bare process execution.

It would be interesting to understand what Alpine does or has that causes such dramatic performance degradation. Also, why anyone, at least in this forum, has experienced a similar issue?

Comment: Alpine uses a musl libc, which is built to optimize for compactness and correctness over performance, whereas glibc optimizes for performance over code size (adding a lot of architecture-specific optimizations and the like). It'd be a very fact-intensive investigation to determine why this matters so much in your case; tooling like oprofile is probably where I'd reach.

Comment: That said, Stack Overflow is not a forum. We don't welcome requests for "similar experiences" -- the goal is to have narrow, specific questions with canonical answers. Bringing this down to a more specific question probably calls for doing the investigation with a profiler to determine which specific call in Alpine (and presumably its libc) is slow, build a [MRE] with a microbenchmark that exercises that call, and ask about that more narrowly.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and clarification on Stack Overflow. You are right.